# Check if the array contain multiple same values in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array like below

```
$array1 = Array
(
    [0] => 20225,2017-02-20
    [1] => 20225,2017-02-20
    [2] => 10027,2017-02-20
    [3] => 10027,2017-02-20
    [4] => 10021,2017-02-20
    [5] => 20205,2017-02-20
    [6] => 50003,2017-02-20
    [7] => 20225,2017-02-20
    [8] => 20205,2017-02-20
    [9] => 10021,2017-02-20
    [10] => 50003,2017-02-20
    [11] => 10027,2017-02-20
    [12] => 20225,2017-02-20
    [13] => 20225,2017-02-21
    [14] => 20225,2017-02-21
)
```

if the array contain same result more than 2, I want to get one of those values to another array called `$array2`.

Please help me to do this

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Your question title and what you want is completely two far different things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As You said:- *if the array contain same result more than 2, I want to get one of those values to another array called `$array2.`*

You can do it like below:-

```
$array_new = array_count_values($array1);
$array2 = array();
foreach($array_new as $key=>$val){
    if($val >1){ //or do $val >2 based on your desire
      $array2[] = $key;
    }
}
print_r($array2);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/834306   OR  https://eval.in/834402

If you want to check that array contains duplicates or not then you can do like this:-

```
if(count(array_unique($array1)) < count($array1)){
  echo "Array have some duplicates";
}else{
  echo "Array have unique elements";
}
```

Output:-https://eval.in/834312

If you want to get only unique array then you can do like below:-

```
$array1 = array_values (array_unique($array1));
```

Output:- https://eval.in/834317

Comment: ** if the array contain same result more than 2** so i changed `$val >1` to `$val >2`. Nice answer :)  !!!

Answer (score 6):

You can use this simple function to check if your array has duplicates:

```
function array_has_dupes($array) {
   return count($array) !== count(array_unique($array));
}
```

Here is the usage:

```
<?php

$array = Array
(
    '0' => '20225,2017-02-20',
    '1' => '20225,2017-02-20',
    '2' => '10027,2017-02-20',
    '3' => '10027,2017-02-20',
    '4' => '10021,2017-02-20',
    '5' => '20205,2017-02-20',
    '6' => '50003,2017-02-20',
    '7' => '20225,2017-02-20',
    '8' => '20205,2017-02-20',
    '9' => '10021,2017-02-20',
    '10' => '50003,2017-02-20',
    '11' => '10027,2017-02-20',
    '12' => '20225,2017-02-20',
    '13' => '20225,2017-02-21',
    '14' => '20225,2017-02-21'
);

$arr_unique = array_unique($array);
$check = count($array) !== count($arr_unique);
$message = 'No duplicates found.';
$arr_duplicates = [];
if($check == 1) {
    $message = "Duplicates found.";
    $arr_duplicates = array_diff_assoc($array, $arr_unique);
}

echo $message;
print_r($arr_duplicates);
?>
```

Btw, [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
 $array1 = [
    [20225,'2017-02-20'],
    [20225,'2017-02-20'],
    [10027,'2017-02-20'],
    [10027,'2017-02-20'],
    [10021,'2017-02-20'],
    [20205,'2017-02-20'],
    [50003,'2017-02-20'],
    [20225,'2017-02-20'],
    [20205,'2017-02-20'],
    [10021,'2017-02-20'],
    [50003,'2017-02-20'],
    [10027,'2017-02-20'],
    [20225,'2017-02-20'],
    [20225,'2017-02-21'],
    [20225,'2017-02-21']
];

$array2 = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array1)));

echo '<pre>';
print_r(($array2));`
```

it's result will be like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20225
            [1] => 2017-02-20
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10027
            [1] => 2017-02-20
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10021
            [1] => 2017-02-20
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20205
            [1] => 2017-02-20
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 50003
            [1] => 2017-02-20
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20225
            [1] => 2017-02-21
        )

)
```

Comment: did you read question carefully?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$array1 = [
    "20225,2017-02-20", 
    "20225,2017-02-20", 
    "10027,2017-02-20", 
    "10027,2017-02-20", 
    "10027,2017-02-20",
    "10021,2017-02-20"
];

$array_unique = [];
$array2 = []; 

foreach($array1 as $value) { 
    if(!in_array($value, $array_unique)) { 
        $array_unique[] = $value;
    } else {
        $array2[] = $value; 
    }
}

echo 'Unique Values: ';
print_r($array_unique);

echo '<hr /> Duplicate Values: ';
print_r(array_unique($array2));
```

Check in:-  http://phptester.net/